# CSS selector to return pre tags inside tables with at least two columns

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am applying manual fixes to html files extracted from legacy chm help files. I would like to detect pre tags inside tables that have at least two columns. I figured out that in Chrome's Console this will give back all pre tags inside table tags:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table pre');
```

Can you advise me how to improve this to return only those pre elements which are inside table that have at least two columns?

Comment: I feel like there would be another way to tackle what you're wanting to achieve. Can you post the HTML of the file?

Comment: What browser are you using? I ask because in the latest version of firefox and chrome it renders the pre tags outside of the table. For me, the following worked: window.document.querySelectorAll("pre");

Comment: @JonathanChaplin: I use Chrome to make the changes to the file but I print it from IE7 because it was designed for that old thing.

Comment: @WesFoster: If you mean I could reference the id or the class of it, no the html file does not give such assistance.

Comment: I don't think you can't use querySelectorAll in IE7. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288511(v=vs.85).aspx Try using jQuery 1.9 for similar functionality.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin: No, as I wrote I will print from IE7 but the CSS will be used in Chrome (the newest version).

Comment: @hungerstar: But I will use the CSS in Chrome; IE7 is only for printing.

Comment: Ok, did you look at my earlier response? In chrome the pre tags render outside the browser (check your element inspsector). I set up a mock and this worked for me:  window.document.querySelectorAll("pre");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162040/discussion-between-jonathan-chaplin-and-z32a7ul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the has selector, at time of writing it's not supported in document.querySelectorAll, however this got me everything with at least 2 columns in chrome:

```
$("table tr:has(td:nth-of-type(2))")
```

Comment: pre is rendered in normal IE7 inside td.

Comment: I tried window.document.querySelectorAll("pre"): it gives back all pre elements (but I need filtering: it should return only those that are inside of a table with at least two columns)

Comment: I tried table td:nth-of-type(2), too: it gives back only those pre elements which are in the second column of a table. I would like to get also those pre elements which are in e.g. the first column of a three-column table.

Comment: Ok, I understand. is a JQuery solution acceptable or are you strictly trying to use querySelectorAll ?

Comment: I don't have much experience with JQuery, but if it works from Chrome's Console, I would give it a try.

Comment: I still think there's some discrepency between what you're seeing and what I'm seeing. So if the above doesn't work try $("table pre:has(td:nth-of-type(2))")

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found that the 'has' selector is not yet supported in Chrome. However, your mentioning jQuery started me in the good direction, and I refined my javascript to this: [ ... document.querySelectorAll( "table" ) ].filter( function( t ) { var multicolumn = false; t.querySelectorAll( "tr" ).forEach( function( r ) { if( 1 < r.querySelectorAll( "td" ).length ) { multicolumn = true; } } ); return multicolumn; } ).forEach( function( t ) { t.querySelectorAll( "pre" ).forEach( function( p ) { console.log( p ); } ); } );

Comment: After I made the post I thought about filter, glad I could help!